# How to concatenate unique values in a column, but doing it only by rowise in R

Tags: r, concatenation

Here is the data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(col = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "bb","bb","bb"),
                               ptnt = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"))
```

I want to group by ptnt and create a new column that will have the output aa-bb-cc-aa-bb

I tried dplyr

```
group_by(ptnt) %>% 
 mutate(output = toString(unique(col))
```

but that only gives aa-bb-cc

Comment: `unique()` looks for only unique values - the second and third set of "aa" are identical to the first so are dropped.  It seems like what you want is a way to drop sequential duplicates, yes?

Comment: Just for avoidance of doubt: do you intend `ptnt` to comprise two values: "a" and "a," i.e. the letter 'a' on its own and the letter 'a,' with a comma?

Comment: There is a typo: the base R function should be `toString()`

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen Yes that's correct.

Comment: @Peter you are right, there was typo in the dataframe. I meant "a" , "a"

Comment: Could you correct the question and does the suggested answer  address the question: it was based on all `a`s only

Comment: @Peter Well the "a" is just a group by condition, I would have other variables in that column too. like "z","z","z" and within the that group I'd want the same unique value concatenation to be repeated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  could do this by adding a variable which identifies each change of `col` and `ptnt`.

I've assumed variable `ptnt` comprises `a`s rather than a mix of `a` and `a,`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>  
  mutate(unq = c(FALSE, col[-length(col)] != col[-1]),
         unq = cumsum(unq))|> 
  distinct() |> 
  group_by(ptnt) |>  
  mutate(output = toString(col))

#> # A tibble: 5 × 4
#> # Groups:   ptnt [1]
#>   col   ptnt    unq output            
#>   <chr> <chr> <int> <chr>             
#> 1 aa    a         0 aa, bb, cc, aa, bb
#> 2 bb    a         1 aa, bb, cc, aa, bb
#> 3 cc    a         2 aa, bb, cc, aa, bb
#> 4 aa    a         3 aa, bb, cc, aa, bb
#> 5 bb    a         4 aa, bb, cc, aa, bb
```

data

```
df <- data.frame(col = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "aa", "aa", "bb"),
                 ptnt = c("a","a","a","a","a","a"))
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I guess it works specifically for the above example, but I want to be able to reproduce at a large scale . And for some reason it wouldn't work when there are numerous rows. In some instances I see aa,aa,aa,aa,aa,bb repeating for a while :/ any idea why that would be the case?

Comment: It would be a good idea to make the question more representative of the actual use case; it may be better to start a new question.